# How can I find the maximum value of a group of numbers near a number in Python?

Tags: python, indexing, max, where-clause

I know the question is confusing, but let me explain. I have decibel and frequency arrays and I want to find the maximum dB near certain frequencies. For example, I'm looking for the maximum Db near 100 Hz +/-.05 Hz (a band of 99.5-100.5 Hz). The arrays contain a lot of data and cover 0-1000 Hz. I'm trying to find this information at several frequency locations.

I've tried using list.index and numpy.where to form a smaller array of just the data points near where I'm interested in. Then I can use max() to find the value that I need. I've either approached this incorrectly and/or the run time for this approach is too long. Is there a more efficient approach to this?

Comment: Are you saying you have two corresponding arrays--a freq_array and a db_array, and you want to find the max in a range in the db_array based upon a start/stop frequency search range?

Comment: Can you give us a fragment of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**orderred frequencies**

If your frequencies list is ordered, you can use the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) library to efficiently find the index of a given frequency in the list. You can then use the same index in the decibels list to pickup the corresponding decibel value.

```py
frequency_list = [...]
decibel_list = [...]

f = 100

i = bisect.bisect_left(frequency_list, f)
db = decibel_list[i]
```

Even if *frequency_list* doesn’t contains *f*, you’ll get a valid index.

You can use this principle to extract a sample of values ​​from a frequency range.

Say your range is `[f1, f2]`, where *f1* = *f* - .5 and *f2* = *f* + .5

You can try:

```py
i1 = bisect.bisect_left(frequency_list, f1)
i2 = bisect.bisect_left(frequency_list, f2)
sample = decibel_list[i1:i2]
db = max(sample)
```

**Unordered frequencies**

If the frequencies list is unordered, you can't use the previous solution.
Another solution is to create a mapping between each frequency and each decibel.
Then, you can extract a sample from this mapping and take the maximum value:

```py
mapping = {f: db for f, db in zip(frequency_list, decibel_list)}

f1 = 100 - 0.5
f2 = 100 + 0.5

sample = [db for f, db in mapping.items() if f1 <= f <= f2]
db = max(sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
def maxValueNear(numbers, target, tolerance):
    maxVal = numbers[0]
    for value in numbers:
        if(target - tolerance <= value and value <= target + tolerance):
            if(value > maxVal):
                maxVal = value    

    return maxVal
```

Where you check the value against your max picking only elements in the range (target-tolerance, target+tolerance)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two corresponding arrays

(1) a freq_array and a db_array

(2) the two arrays have corresponding indexes

```
def find_max(db_array, freq_array, start_freq, end_freq, default_val = 0):
    " Finds max in db_array between start_freq & end_freq"

    # Uses a generator
    # default_val returned by max when no values in frequency range
    return max((x for i, x in enumerate(db_array) if start_freq <= freq_array[i] <= end_freq), default=default_val)
```

**Example Usage**

```
# Search from 99.5 to 100.5 Hz with a default of 0
peak = find_max(db_array, freq_array, 99.5, 100.5)
#>>> max value or 0.0 (if no values in range)

# Search from 99.5 to 100.5 Hz with a default of negative infinity
peak = find_max(db_array, freq_array, 99.5, 100.5, float("-inf"))
# max value or -inf (if no values in range)
```